# How to express exclusive intersections?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions

I have a function $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow\mathbb{R}, \ \mathbf{x} \mapsto \sum_{i = 1}^{n} w_i \mathbf{1}_{A_i}(\mathbf{x})$ for $w_i \in \mathbb{R}$ and the $A_i$s **are allowed to intersect**. Thus for the case of $n=3$ we might have something like:

[image]

($A_1 = A, A_2 = B, A_3 = C$ here)

where at each *exclusive* intersection e.g. $AB = A \cap B \setminus C$, $f$ takes the value $w_A + w_B$. Now, I would like to express $f$ as the sum of indicators over **non-intersecting** sets (i.e. a partition of the underlying space):

$$f(\mathbf{x}) = (w_A + w_B + w_C) \mathbf{1}_{ABC}(\mathbf{x}) + (w_A + w_B) \mathbf{1}_{AB}(\mathbf{x}) + (w_A + w_C) \mathbf{1}_{AC}(\mathbf{x}) + \ldots$$

**How to express this for general $n$?** (In the same vein as [XOR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR), the notion of exclusive intersection would really help here, but I'm unsure of its notation.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X=\{A_1,A_2,\ldots, A_n\}$.
For each $S\in\mathcal P(X)$ denote $M(S)=\bigcup S\setminus \bigcup(\mathcal P(X)\setminus S)$ and $W_S=\sum_{A\in S}w_A$. Then 
$$f(x)=\sum_{S\subseteq X} W_S\mathbf 1_{M(S)}$$ is such a sum. Note that $M(S)$ is the "exclusive intersections" of all $A_i\in S$.

Alternatively, we have a map $\phi\colon\mathbb R^2\to X$, $\mathbb x\mapsto \{A\in X\mid x\in A\}$ and can write $\phi^{-1}(S)$ isntead of $M(S)$ above.

Comment: I think it might be $M(S) = \bigcap S \setminus \ldots$ though. Thanks